# How to show mysql results using two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I created two tables - 1 for jobs and 1 for applications. When a user applies for a job, the `job id` is inserted into applications table.

My question is: After a user has applied to a job, how can I show only jobs that he didn't apply to?

Comment: show your tables structure(schema)

Comment: Use an `INNER JOIN` in conjunction with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, it should be an exluding LEFT JOIN or a NOT EXISTS condition.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel  join with all applications, filter by where appl.id <> currentUserId - ok left join to include jobs without applications

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, but you won't get any jobs which have no applications yet (because of inner join).

Comment: @R.rere, you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name` to get the table schema/structure and post it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make out with this... hope it helps.

```sql
select jobid 
from jobs
where jobid not in(select jobid from applications where userid/username=person)
```

Comment: sure... can you post the sample data used in both of your tables?

Comment: Okay... here what the user wants is to get the list of jobs from jobs table. SELECT JOBID does try to get the rows from the job table. to avoid jobs that are not listed in the applications table we are using NOT IN with a subquery where the sub query returns the list of jobs that are applied for. requested for ref tables to make the explination more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a mysql query like this :

First: select unique job_id from application table, and store them into array.

Second : select all jobs except those in the previous array:

```
Select * from jobs where id not in ($array);
```